# Female Breadboard Jumper Cables

Tags: gpio, cable, breadboard

Can I use the inexpensive female/male or female/female breadboard jumper cables to temporarily wire sensors to the GPIO pins?

http://www.ebay.ca/itm/QTY30-Breadboard-Jumpers-Wires-Male-Female-Arduino-PIC-Hard-Case-/370655916049

http://dx.com/p/30cm-breadboard-wires-for-electronic-diy-40-cable-pack-80207?item=5

[image]

Comment: Why should this not be bepossible? I can't understand why this question get's upvotes... It's like asking "Can I use a Ethernet-Cable to connect LAN?"

Comment: @Mose - size and spacing of pins.

Comment: @Mose - the purpose of this site, and the very purpose of the Pi itself, is to encourage learning. Unfortunately, I was not born with innate knowledge of header pin spacing (and I'd guess neither were the upvoters! :).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes you can, I used some I bought at a computer-parts store

[image]

<sub>(Maplin A39GF "Colour Single Pin Interconnect Cables" / "Single Pin Mbrd Ext")</sub>

Answer (score 5):

Yes.

This is what I am using, and what is recommended by Adafruit and supplied with [SkPangs Raspberry Pi Starter Kits](https://www.skpang.co.uk/catalog/starter-kita-for-raspberry-pi-pi-not-include-p-1070.html).